# Can I connect by using double/nested proxy?

Tags: proxy, socks-proxy, http-proxy, proxy-server

Suppose that I want to connect to internet through proxy server A. If I am in a network where connection to external network should go through proxy server B, is it possible to do this? Is there any way to use nested/double proxy like this?

> **my computer** --> **proxy B** --> **proxy A** --> **internet**

**Edit**

I have no control either to **proxy A** or **proxy B**, can only control **my computer**.

Comment: Yes, it's how the [`Tor`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tor_%28anonymity_network%29) network essentially works. Setting up something like this, however, is another story and will depend on a lot of different factors.

Answer (score 1):

For SOCKS this is fairly straightforward if you know where all the proxies are, you just ask each one to connect to the next.

For HTTP, to specify an upstream proxy, you'd need to use the CONNECT method to get the proxy to connect to the next proxy.

Comment: Any applicable example (command line, Firefox config, etc) please?

Comment: sorry, I thought you were doing this in code.  Browsers don't support this.  You'd need to use something like proxifier which I believe can support nested proxies.

Comment: yes it can see https://www.proxifier.com/documentation/v3/chain.htm

Comment: Nice info, I found also proxychain (have not try yet) for Linux